# JavaScript add class on click works in IE9, doesn't work in IE7-8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, click, replace, checked

I'm using a script to:

1. toggle the class of my checkbox replacement element
2. change the state of the checkbox itself
3. initialize the state of the checkbox replacement based on the state of the checkbox itself

It works fine in every browser (including IE9) but fails in IE7 and IE8.
In IE7 - 8 clicking the element has no effect. It neither adds the class nor changes the checkbox state.

```
/** BEGIN CheckBox **/
$.fn.xCheckBoxList = function () {
    this.Check = function (clientId, isSingleSelection) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var checkBox = $("#" + clientId + " .x_checkBox");
            $(checkBox).has("input:checked").addClass("x_checkBoxChecked");
            $(checkBox).click(function () {
                if (isSingleSelection) {
                    $(this).siblings().find("input").attr("checked", false);
                }
                $(checkBox).has("input:checked").addClass("x_checkBoxChecked");
                $(checkBox).has("input:not(:checked)").removeClass("x_checkBoxChecked");
            });
        });
    }

    return this;
}
/** END CheckBox **/
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I added an alert before the "if (isSingleSelection)" and in firefox/IE9 the event fires twice, in IE8 only once. I'll try and check the html code and classes.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. It seems that simply addClass and other Mootools 1.2 methods do not work in IE8. Some alternative implementations should be provided to make this work in IE8.
If you have found a better solution please let us know